# Python with Ray for DB Insertion Parallel Processing

Tags: python-3.x, ray

I am trying to Insert into Oracle DB about 1 M Records and I am trying to make it more faster
I was searching for a solution till find Ray with Python
I tried to develop and when I run, nothing happens, no record is inserted
What's wrong with my code?!

```
import ray
import cx_Oracle
            def gen_sql_statements():
            # Here to catch the Insert statements
            return statements_list
        
        
    @ray.remote    
        class OraDbTable:
        
            Gen_String = 'system/password@localhost:1521/orcl'
        
        
            def __init__(self):
                db = cx_Oracle.connect(self.Gen_String)
                self.cursor = db.cursor()
        
            def update_ddb_item(self, sql):
                self.cursor.execute(sql)
                self.cursor.commit()
        
        num_of_actors = 4
        actors_list = [OraDbTable.remote() for _ in range(num_of_actors)]
        st_list = gen_sql_statements()
        result_ids = []
        for counter, row in enumerate(st_list):
             actor_index = counter % num_of_actors
             result_ids.append(actors_list[actor_index].update_ddb_item.remote(row))
        
        ray.get(result_ids)
```